# How to stop Activity attached AlertDialog keep reappearing over Activity after Activity paused and recreated?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I am working on project, which simply validates through username and password.

I made some progress with using DialogFragments and AlertDialog. AlertDialog appears after starting the app over the mainactivity asking for username and password. 
I must set the Alertdialog's setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false) and DialogFragment's setCancelable(false) because I don't want the users to dismiss it with pressing android's back button.

The problem is, after dismissing it programatically on successful login, if the activity becomes invisible and visible again , the Alertdialog's OnShowListener called, showing this AlertDialog again.

Can I somehow "detach" this AlertDialog from Activity? This popups also happen after unlocking the screen and getting back to activity which makes it very annoying...

Here is the code of interest:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(GlobalInformations.getInstance().getUsername()==null){
        shownoticeDialog();
    }
}

public void shownoticeDialog(){
    DialogFragment dialogFragment = new NoticeDialogFragment();
    dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "NoticeDialogFragment");
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogFragment dialog) {
   //set the username on a TextView instance, etc...
}
```

NoticeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment

```
public class NoticeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public interface NoticeDialogListener{
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDismiss(DialogFragment dialog);
}

NoticeDialogListener mListener;
static Activity activity = null;
//static String username;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        activity = (Activity) context;
        mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;

    } catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "must implement NoticeDialogListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);

    final AutoCompleteTextView actv_username = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
    final EditText password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password);

    getavailableusernames(actv_username);

    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.AlertDialogCustom))
            .setView(view)
            .setTitle("Login")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
            //.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create();

    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            final Button button =((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String passw = password.getText().toString();
                    String user = actv_username.getText().toString();
                    try{
                        if(user.length()<4 || passw.length()<4){
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Username/password too short", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                        else {
                            //login to account, if success dismiss.
                          login(user, passw,dialog);
                        }


                    } catch(Exception e){

                    }
                    //  dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    // set the DialogFragment to make the dialog unable to dismiss with back button
    // (because not working if called on the dialog directly)
    this.setCancelable(false);

    return dialog;
}

 public void login(final String username, String password, final AlertDialog dialog){

    boolean login_success = false;
    //query the credentials
    login_success = dosomesqlquery(username, password);

    if(login_success){
         dialog.dismiss();
    }
 }

//passing the handling to activity...
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    mListener.onDismiss(NoticeDialogFragment.this);
}

}
```

Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: Why don’t you create a boolean flag and when the user logs in correctly it would set to true and before showing the dialog, check whether user is logged or not using this flag

Comment: Hi Mate, did u implement onResume in your activity? From the code fragment of your mainactivity, I cant see onResume(). onResume is called when the activity lays in backstack and the focus comes back to your activity. Otherwise onCreate is called, where you if(GlobalInformations.getInstance().getUsername()==null){
        shownoticeDialog();
    }

Comment: Hi no, I did not. But I think I had a misconception then. I thought onCreate() always called after activity gains focus. I will correct that.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is that kind of situation where I end up heading my desk continously.

The source of the problem was I called dialog.dismiss() which dismisses the dialog, BUT not the dialogfragment itself, so will never, ever dismissed, even if the dialog disappeared from screen. Placing this.dismiss() in NoticeDialogFragment's onDismiss or anywhere else after login succeded will let the application act as it should.

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    mListener.onDismiss(NoticeDialogFragment.this);
    this.dismiss(); //will dismiss the DialogFragment. Yeeey!
}
```

Thank you for your time and answers as they helped me point out the real problem. I will modify the code based on your suggestions.

Comment: you can also call `dismiss()` only

Answer (score 1):

Set the value when the activity goes background

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean("authUser", GlobalInformations.getInstance().getUsername()==null)
}
```

and read it when it comes back

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("authUser")) {
         boolean authUser = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("authUser", false);
         if(authUser) {
             //show or don't show dialog
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe that is a silly question, but where can I find that getBoolean(String, boolean) method of yours? I can only see static java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean 
getBoolean(String).

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to use a static variable in your activity using two steps.

1. Declare a global static boolean

   `private static boolean session = false;`
2. Check if the boolean has changed and if not, set the boolean to true when the dialog is shown

   public void shownoticeDialog(){
   if(session)return;
   DialogFragment dialogFragment = new NoticeDialogFragment();
   dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "NoticeDialogFragment");
   session = true;
   }

Comment: Does not work. Still keep popping up, still wonder why. The funny thing is, in debug mode I can not even see what calls the onShowListener again.